# Extract a part of a string in a bash script

Tags: shell-script, string

I have a variable with some text in it. I need to get a specific bit of information out of it. For example I have

```
export OUTPUT="Running \"protractor:admin\" (protractor) task Using ChromeDriver directly... [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver Jasmine version: 1.3.1 revision 1354556913 SauceOnDemandSessionID=5c72e54365e9bb559ea389dc164ba754 job-name=Admin"
```

I need `5c72e54365e9bb559ea389dc164ba754` in an variable `SAUCE_ID`. The actual SessionID changes each run of the script so I need someway to pull it out. It is always preceded by `SauceOnDemandSessionID=` and followed by `job-name=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the shell's string manipulation features that come with [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). These features are present in all non-antique Bourne-style shells including dash, bash and ksh.

```
suffix=${OUTPUT#*SauceOnDemandSessionID=}
SAUCE_ID=${suffix%%[!0-9A-Fa-f]*}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is always the same length, and composed of only the letters a through f and numbers, and there are no similar strings in the output, you could do this:

```
SAUCE_ID="$(echo $OUTPUT | egrep -o '[0-9a-f]{32}')"
```

It searches for a string of 32 characters that are either a number in 0-9 or a letter in a-f.

To allow variation in the length of the string, use something like this:

```
SAUCE_ID="$(echo $OUTPUT | egrep -o '[0-9a-f]{26,38}')"
```

This example matches any of those strings with between 26 and 38 characters. You could also use this to match strings with at least 26 characters:

```
SAUCE_ID="$(echo $OUTPUT | egrep -o '[0-9a-f]{26,}')"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not 100% the length will always be 32.

Comment: It's possible to allow multiple lengths. I edited my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with PCRE, you can use the regex:

```
SauceOnDemandSessionID=\K[^ ]*(?= job-name)
```

**Test:**

```
$ SAUCE_ID=$(grep -Po "SauceOnDemandSessionID=\K[^ ]*(?= job-name)" <<< "$OUTPUT")
$ echo "$SAUCE_ID"
5c72e54365e9bb559ea389dc164ba754
```

It will be work in all cases given you have `SauceOnDemandSessionID=` before and `job-name` after the pattern.

Comment: I get: 
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: @Justin808: How did you run it?